# Adding collection to listbox from another form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to add a collection from one form to the listbox of the other.

I have two forms, `MainForm` and `StaffForm`.
In the `StaffForm`, the user is able to add *name* and *qualifications* and then have the option to click either **OK** or **Cansel**.

If the user clicks OK, the collection is added on a listbox in the `MainForm`.

Here is how I tried it.

Here is my `StaffForm`:

```
 public partial class StaffForm : Form
    {
        private Staff m_staff;
        ListManager<Staff> m_qualifications = new ListManager<Staff>();
        public StaffForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (m_staff == null)
                m_staff = new Staff();
        }
        public Staff Staff
        {
            get { return m_staff; }
            set { m_staff = value; }
        }

        private void ReadValues(Staff staff)
        {
            staff.Qualifications.Add(qualificationtxt.Text);
        }

        public void UpdateResults()
        {
            Resultlst.Items.Clear();  //Erase current list

            //Get one elemnet at a time from manager, and call its 
            //ToString method for info - send to listbox
            for (int index = 0; index < m_qualifications.Count; index++)
            {
                Staff staff = m_qualifications.GetAt(index);
                //Adds to the list.
                Resultlst.Items.Add(staff);
            }
        }

        private void OKbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Addbtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Staff n_staff = new Staff();
            m_qualifications.Add(n_staff);

            ReadValues(n_staff);
            UpdateResults();
        }
    }
```

Here is the `MainForm`:

```
  public MainForm()
        {
            //Visual Studio initializations
            InitializeComponent();

private void staffbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StaffForm staffForm = new StaffForm();

            if(staffForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foodItemslst.Items.Add(staffForm.Staff.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(staffForm.Staff.ToString());
            }
        }
```

The collection in `StaffManager` is working. The problem is sending it over to `MainForm`

I'm not getting any error. When the user clicks OK nothing happens to the listbox.

Comment: You haven't told us what “the problem ” is. You're getting an error? Show us the error. You can't access `staffForm.Staff` from `staffbtn_Click`? That's because you made `staffForm.Staff` private. It has to be public to be used by an external class.

Comment: I'm not getting any error. When the user clicks OK nothing happens to the listbox.

The property `Staff` is public in `StaffForm`

Comment: I solved it! The problem was that I forgot to set the `OK button`'s dialog to OK